# Selenium Webdriver : Difference between Implicit wait, Explicit wait and Fluent wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I would like to know the difference between Implicit wait , explicit wait and Fluent which is available in Selenium WebDriver. Which wait we would prefer to go  in what situation?

Need some samples.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search these things on google. There are a lot of websites which explains these. Refrain yourself from asking such questions here. For your reference find below links:

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/

http://selenium4freshers.blogspot.in/2014/06/implicit-wait-vs-explicit-wait-vs.html

http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

Comment: Thanks Abhinav :) Actually what i was expected here is, Both Explicit and Fluent wait are doing the same operation. Then Why do we need Fluent Wait here? We can say like Fluent wait is having facility to check in pollingEvery() method and we can avoid one exception. But the same way, Explicit wait also doing the same. It will wait for the time we have given and if it finds immediately it will return true. the whats the difference?

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid"))); in this condition, will the driver wait for 10 whole seconds even if  the element available in 2 seconds and then it will return true? or it will return true once element available on pagein 2 seconds?

Comment: It will wait for the element to be clickable upto a maximum of 10 seconds as specified. If it element does not get clickable withing 10 seconds then it will fail else as soon as it becomes clickable it will click on it.

Comment: thanks Abhinav. There i got stuck to understand the concept of Explicit wait and Fluent wait.  Both are waiting for the maximum time and  when the element available then it will move to next action like click etc.,Fluent wait also doing the same as explicit wait. Then why we need Fluent wait?

Comment: FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition

Comment: Hi Abhinav, In explicit wait also we can define maximum amount of time for a condition and once the element is available on page, next action will be take place. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webelement)));

Comment: if that is the case, then why we need FluentWait in Webdriver? One point i noted in Fluent wait is we can ignore one exception. But this can be done using explicit wait also. I don't figure out how exactly both are different? in which situation we should use?

Comment: Fluent wait polls in every polling time. Read the links. This is not an issue. If you need to clarify anything refer to links or google it.